# Set of all subsets

Tags: python, set, subset

In Python2 I could use

```
def subsets(mySet):
    return reduce(lambda z, x: z + [y + [x] for y in z], mySet, [[]])
```

to find all subsets of `mySet`. Python 3 has removed `reduce`.

What would be an equally concise rewrite of this for Python3?

Comment: `reduce()` is still there -- it was moved to `functools`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Ah, thanks. Is there a non-`reduce()` version?

Comment: Not quite a one-liner, but the [itertools docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html) have a powerset implementation.

Comment: It's not written as a 1-liner, but could be munged into one: `chain.from_iterable(combinations(list(iterable), r) for r in range(len(list(iterable))+1))`

Comment: @AdamParkin: Thanks. Where does `chain` come from?

Comment: Can I use it to generate a [set of all sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell's_paradox)?

Comment: @Randomblue it'll be so kind of you if can you please explain the code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a [list](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#Python) of several possible implementations of the power set (the set of all subsets) algorithm in Python. Some are recursive, some are iterative, some of them don't use `reduce`. Plenty of options to choose from!

Answer (score 5):

The function `reduce()` can always be reaplaced by a `for` loop.  Here's a Python implementation of `reduce()`:

```
def reduce(function, iterable, start=None):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    if start is None:
        start = next(iterator)
    for x in iterator:
        start = function(start, x)
    return start
```

(In contrast to Python's built-in version of `reduce()`, this version does not allow to pass in `None` as `start` parameter.)

Special-casing this code with the parameters you passed to `reduce()` gives

```
def subsets(my_set):
    result = [[]]
    for x in my_set:
        result = result + [y + [x] for y in result]
    return result
```